# SQL zero instead of null

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, null, zero

This function:

```
for i in Selection: 
    cursor.execute(Query)
    ydata[i] = [int(x[0]) for x in cursor.fetchall()]
```

raises:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int(): NULL if a null value is found.
```

How can I make my query return zeros instead of nulls so that I can fix this? (I am plotting the data, so I cannot add "is not null" to my select statement.

Comment: @relima: What DB interface are you using that returns a Python string `"NULL"` instead of Python `None`?

Comment: @Glenn Maynard Downvoted your comment as 'Noise'. Voted question up for snarky commenter downvote.

Comment: Glenn Maynard: 349 Votes. 282 down votes. 0 questions.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: Ummm I thought `coalesce` was *defined* as a case expression and thus the accepted answer's case option should work anywhere, even on deviant s/w like SQL Server

Comment: I'm the author of APSW.  It does not return the string "NULL" for SQL level null objects - None is returned.  The only way you'd get "NULL" is if that is what your database contains.  I'd suggest fixing the database:  UPDATE table SET column=null WHERE column='NULL'

Comment: @Roger Binns. You are right about the problem. Thanks, I changed the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fix this before it gets to Python with a case statement in your query:

```
CASE WHEN FIELD_NAME IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE FIELD_NAME END,
```

**begin edit**

Other SQL variants do it differently (taken from other answers):

```
COALESCE(FIELD_NAME, 0)
```

or

```
IFNULL(FIELD_NAME, 0)
```

**end edit**

Or handle it in your list comp like so (assumes NULL is a predefined object or constant):

```
ydata[i] = [(int(x[0]) if x[0] != NULL else 0) for x in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Or create a customer conversion function:

```
def field_to_int(val):
    if val == NULL:
        return 0
    else:
        return int(val)

for i in Selection: 
    cursor.execute(Query)
    ydata[i] = [field_to_int(x[0]) for x in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `IFNULL(fieldname, 0) AS fieldname` in the field list of the query.

Comment: This function is nonstandard, and unnecessary; use `coalesce`.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: Compliance with ANSI SQL is overrated and difficult to achieve. And there will be some other SQLLite-dialect specific feature in use somewhere. If this migrated to, say, SQL Server, COALESCE is a liability.

Comment: @gbn: And if `IFNULL` is migrated to Postgresql, *it's* a liability.  Unless the user actually plans to migrate to SQL Server, he should be encouraged to choose the standard function by default.

Answer (score 2):

You'd use [IFNULL](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull)

```
...IFNULL(MyField, 0) AS MyField...
```

Answer (score 2):

The error doesn't make sense; Python doesn't have "NULL", it has "None".

The cleanest thing to do is use SQL coalesce: `SELECT COALESCE(value, 0)` to convert SQL NULL to 0.

If you're getting None, and you know the values are integers, then you can safely say `int(x[0] or 0)`.